# Remove specific definitions from a variable in PHP

Tags: php, email, variables

I have a PHP mail script that validates name, email address, and phone number before sending the mail. This then means that the Name, Email address, and Phone fields are **Required** Fields.

I want to have it so that the *Name* and ***EITHER*** *Email* or *Phone* are required. Such that if a name and phone are inputted, it sends the mail, or if a name and an email are inputted, it also sends the email.

The way the script works right now is it has several IF statements that check for (1) name, (2) email and (3) phone. Here's an example of an if statement of the code:

```
if ( ($email == "") ) {
 $errors .= $emailError; // no email address entered
 $email_error = true;
}
if ( !(preg_match($match,$email)) ) {
 $errors .= $invalidEmailError; // checks validity of email
 $email_error = true; 
}
```

And here's how it sends the mail:

```
   if ( !($errors) ) {
 mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
 echo "<p id='correct'>";
 echo "ההודעה נשלחה בהצלחה!";
 echo "</p>";

} else {
 if (($email_error == true)) {
   $errors != $phoneError; 

   /*echo "<p id='errors'>";
   echo $errors;
   echo "</p>";*/
  }
 if (($phone_error == true)) {
   $errors != $emailError; 
   $errors != $invalidEmailError;

   /*echo "<p id='errors'>";
   echo $errors;
   echo "</p>";*/

  }
 echo "<p id='errors'>";
 echo $errors;
 echo "</p>";
}
```

This doesn't work though. Basically this is what I want to do: If no email address was entered or if it was entered incorrectly, set a variable called $email_error to be true. Then check for that variable, and if it's true, then remove the $phoneError part of the $errors variable.

Man I hope I'm making some sense here. Does anyone know why this doesn't work? It reports all errors if all fields are left empty :(

Thanks!
Amit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need at first to build up an array of errors, i.e.:

```
$errors = array();
if (!$phone) { // add more validation as required
    $errors['phone'] = $phoneError;
}
if (!$email) {
    $errors['email'] = 'No email provided';
}
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $errors['email'] = 'Invalid email provided';
}
```

Then you send, or display the errors:

```
if (!isset($errors['phone']) || !isset($errors['email'])) {
    // send mail here, only if either the phone or the email error is missing
} else {
    // display errors
    echo '<p id="errors">';
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo $error;
    }
    echo '</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

so...

```
$sent=false;
if(!$name){
   $errors[]='No Name was supplied.';
   return($errors);
}
if($phone && validatePhone($phone)){
  //send the phone message however...
  $sent=true;
}
if($email && validateEmail($email)){
  //send the email here...
  $sent=true;
}
if(!$sent){
  $errors[]='Neither an email or a phone was supplied';
  return($errors);
}
```

classed:

```
class Communication {
    var $sent=false;
    var $errors=false;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->phone=$_POST['phone'];
        $this->email=$_POST['email'];
        $this->name=$_POST['name'];
        if($this->validateName()){
            $this->validateEmail();
            $this->validatePhone();
        }

    }
    public function validateEmail(){
        //do your regex here and eval either false or true to $status
        if(!$status){
            $this->errors['ErrorInvalidEmail']=ErrorInvalidEmail;
        }else{
            $this->sendEmail();

        }
    }

    public function validatePhone(){
         //do your regex here and eval either false or true to $status
        if(!$status){
            $this->errors['ErrorInvalidPhone']=ErrorInvalidPhone;
        }else{
            $this->sendText();

        }

    }
    public function validateName(){
         //do your regex here and eval either false or true to $status
        if(!$status){
           $this->errors['ErrorInvalidName']=ErrorInvalidName;
           return(false);
        }else{
            return(true);
        }

    }
    public function sendEmail(){
        $this->sent=true;
        //do your sending by email HERE

    }
    public function sendText(){
         $this->sent=true;
         // do your sending by text/phone here

    }
}

$c=new Communication();
print_r($c->errors);
```

Comment: you can also move the validate methods inside the if statement and add to the $errors stack on invalid formats...

Comment: I suspect this will work, but will require some rewriting on my end. Is there a simple way to remove definitions from variables? Say for example, I have `$errors = $a . $b`, and then I want to remove `$b` from `$errors`, is there a way to do such a thing? Sort of like, `$errors = $errors - $b`, but that doesn't work.

Comment: that's why I stack them in an array. if you want you can stack them with a key, and then remove specific keys... such as $errors['emailInvalid']='Your Email appears to be invalid'  and then remove it by using unset($errors['emailInvalid']);

Comment: Get used to writing your code in a class structure and keep your functions as small as reasonable. it makes for better reusability, and makes reorganizing code faster.

Comment: I think that's exactly what I'll do. Perfect, thanks! I'll try it now and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

I believe

```
if ( !($errors) )
```

should be

```
if ( !$errors )
//or
if( !isset( $errors ) )
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. The script works in testing for errors. It tests all three fields (name, phone, email) for errors and if such errors exist, stores all three in an $errors variable. Then tests the $errors variable to see if it's empty, if it is, sends mail, if not, echo $errors. I want it to now test to see that IF email field is invalid but phone field is valid, STILL send mail. and if phone field is invalid but email field is valid, STILL send mail. AKA only one of the two (phone/email) must be required, but it has no specifications on which

Answer (score 0):

While there is no benefit over doing it Selsaek's way (above), one way to do it is with a bit mask (a set of constants which are powers of 2, and one storage variable). You OR the storage variable with the constant, and then when you AND the two together later, a nonzero result means the flag was tripped. No reason you can't use an array to store the flag and the text:

```
$WARNING_MASK = array('name' => 1, 'email' => 2, 'phone' => 4);
$warningflag = 0;
```

to set a flag an error (you OR the storage variable with a constant):

```
$warningflag = $warningflag | $WARNING_MASK['name'];
```

to test for an error (you AND the storage value with the constant):

```
if ($warningflag & $WARNING_MASK['name']) {}
```